# "He wore [a] wig: which wig was made of hair" -- Is this 'which' a resumptive pronoun?

Tags: resumptive-pronouns

While reading *A Tale of Two Cities* by Charles Dickens, I noticed this sentence:
<sup>(Note: The sentence in the title of this question was shortened due to limited space.)</sup>

> He wore an odd little sleek crisp flaxen wig, setting very close to his head: **which wig**, it is to be presumed, was made of hair, but which looked far more as though it were spun from filaments of silk or glass.

This *which wig* sounds a bit odd to me and I wonder if it's a [resumptive pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resumptive_pronoun), but maybe it was because it was written about 150 years ago and English was a little different than it is nowadays. In Present-Day English, I'd expect something like this:

- *He wore an odd little sleek crisp flaxen wig, ...: **this wig**, ..., was made of hair, ...*
- *He wore an odd little sleek crisp flaxen wig, ...: **which the/this wig**, ..., was made of hair, ...*

Personally, I don't believe that Dickens would write anything ungrammatical, so I wonder how we should justify or explain this *which wig*?

Comment: **Which** is an adjective, not a pronoun.

Comment: The sentence of Dickens is unlike the examples of "salvaging" a sentence which has gone off the tracks, which salvaging is described on that wiki page. What it has in common with those examples is the "distance" between antecedent and relative.

Comment: I don't know what a contemporary grammarian would call it, but *relative adjective* is what I'd call it. The construction is very common in late Middle English and in the 15th c.

Comment: I found [this question on the English Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74357/why-does-legal-english-sometimes-repeat-the-antecedent-noun-after-which), which appears to be about the same structure.  I don't think the answers there really explain the structure other than to say it's a way to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @TRomano +1 on the "distance" point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Which* in Dickens's sentence is used as what some modern grammars (*Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, e.g.) call a *relative determinative.* The clause beginning with "which wig" is a supplementary relative, and the *determinative which* is used here in what CGEL (p. 1040) refers to as *upward percolation.* Here the relative feature, anteceded by *wig* in the main clause, percolates up from the *determinative which* to the noun phrase *which wig.*

(Note that in Dickens's sentence, the relative feature percolates even further to *which* in the subordinate clause beginning with *but.*)

This usage is seldom seen except in literature or formal writing, and even in those contexts may be less common today than it was in Dickens's time. CGEL (p 1044) provides the following example of this construction:

> i   They refuse to support UN's expenses of maintaining the UN emergency
>   force in
>     the Middle East as a buffer between Egypt and Israel, and the UN troops in the
>     Congo, *which expenses* are not covered by the regular budget.

The authors go on to say of this particular kind of clause and determinative:

> Examples like [i], where the NP concerned is itself an element of clause structure, are quite rare and formal, verging on the archaic.  It is much more usual for the NP to be complement of a preposition which is also fronted, and the head noun is then predominantly one of very general meaning such as *case* or *time* as in [ii-iii].

The reference [ii-iii] is to other examples given in the section:

> ii   I may be late, *in which case* I suggest you start without me.
>   iii  I will return at 3 pm, *by which time* I expect this room to be tidy.

Demonstrating that even the most thorough and comprehensive dictionary is often unreliable where parts of speech are concerned, the OED reflects the view of traditional grammars. It tells us that this is a use of *which* as an ordinary *relative adjective:*

> **III.** Relative uses.
>    * as simple relative.
>
> **6.** *adj*. The ordinary relative adj.
>   ...
>
> <sup>1800   Wordsworth in Wordsworth & S. T. Coleridge *Lyrical Ballads* II. 1   The monuments spoken of in the second Part of the following Poem, *which* monuments do now exist as I have there described them.</sup>
>   ...
>
> <sup>1892   *Photogr. Ann*. II. 883   A 5 × 4 camera..(which size is now the most popular).</sup>

Comment: Someone [suggested an edit](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/47684), which I've rejected on the grounds that it should be a comment rather than an edit.  I'll reproduce the text here, which is in response to the sentence at the end of your answer: "most entries in the OED have not been (fully) updated since 1928, so the last date of citation does not mean anything as to today's usage in many cases"

Comment: A more modern analysis, one which takes into account the distinction between adjectives and determiners, might call this a **relative determiner** instead.  (Unfortunately, due to terminological squabbles, some linguists would use the term **relative determinative** instead.)

Comment: @snailplane I'm aware of the squabbles and of the more modern terminology. My answer is an unvarnished attempt to avoid the issue entirely, on the principle that such things as the distinction between _determiner_ and _determinative_ are of limited value to a new learner of English, and can appear picayune and even silly to the layman. On reflection, though, it might be worthwhile to add something on the subject to the answer, so I'm a-cogitatin on it.

Comment: @snailplane I overlooked your earlier comment. It's true that lots of OED citations are outdated. Not surprising considering the breadth of the work! A note to that effect probably does belong in this answer for the benefit of future searchers. I can add something. I really sort of dashed the answer off. In the case of this particular usage, I don't think anyone would deny that it's only seen today in literature or formal writing. Maybe it was more common in Dickens's time in those contexts, but I daresay that even then folks didn't use it when discussing the price of sole with the fishmonger.

Comment: @snailplane How about it now?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Some pointers in this answer are invaluable, as it points me in the right direction. After taking a while reading relevant pages in CGEL, I think the most relevant page to the structure of our example sentence by Dickens is on page 1044. The examples and explanations on the page are quite enlightening. I wish you included example [26] i to make the quoted text clearer ("..., are quite rare and formal, verging in the archaic. It is much more usual for the NP to be complement of a preposition which is also fronted [*in which case, by which time*]").

Comment: Good advice @DamkerngT. and so edited.

Comment: Speaking of squabbles over doctrine, what is it called in "one of the which true Churches did triumph over all errour...?  https://books.google.com/books?id=nj9FAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA855&dq=%22the+which%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij29-cwfbPAhUi24MKHSa-

Comment: @TRomano Whew! well, "which" here is also in the _prenuclear_ position, although it's not the object of the relative clause. But it seems to me that this is the same case as Dickens's sentence, but with more percolation. The relative feature percolates from _churches_ to the NP that is the object of the partitive _of,_ which is _the which true Churches._ But here the percolation  loops _down_ to the pronoun _one._ So again it's the _relative determinative which._ (In any case, it's a wicked which.)

Comment: Is "one of the which true Churches" different from "one of the said true Churches",  and if so, in what way? Are **which** and **said** both relative determinatives?

Comment: @TRomano In CGEL-speak, yeah, I think they're both relative determinatives. The percolation is still _down_ to the pronoun _one_ through the partitive preposition, though, which is a case that H&P don't explicitly discuss (or I can't find it, anyway.) It might be easier to call both _which_ and _said_ "relative adjectives" in the old style, but the _determinatives_ model allows for more accurate description of what's going on in such sentences.